# How to SUM Totals At Bottom of a Fixed Column in every worksheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to SUM Total Values from **H** Column At Bottom of Column **H** Dynamically on every worksheet.
My code are below:

```
    Sub Sum_All()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select
        Call Sum_This
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    Sub Sum_This()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("H" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(H2:H" & LastRow & ")"
    End With
    End Sub
```

I am trying this code but nothing happen.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.
You maybe need to check on how to write a `With` statement.
Also, when using `For Each` to loop through all WorkSheets in a given WorkBook, you need to use this syntax : `For Each ws In myWorkBook.Worksheets`, `myWorkBook` being a variable reffering to the `WorkBook` you want.

Try this :

```
Sub Sum_All()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("H" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(H2:H" & LastRow & ")"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your are a real excel champ, Perfect Solution, Thank You Very Much Mr. romulax14.

Comment: Glad it worked, please consider accepting the answer by checking the mark on the left of the post (goes from gray to green)